# Localizations of a quotient ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ and $f=x^2$. I have to know what is $R_f$ (localization in the element $x^2$). How can I describe
$\operatorname{Spec}(R_f) $ and $\operatorname{Spec}(R_{(f)})$? How can I imagine $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the elements of $R$ are the polynomial functions on the variety $X$ cut out by the equation $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$.

Elements of the ring $R_f$ have the form $r/f^k$ for some $r \in R$ and some integer $k \geq 0$.  Note that since we may take $r$ to have a factor of $x$ if we like, the ring $R_{x^2}$ is the same as the ring $R_x$.  We can think of $R_f$ as rational functions on $X$ that are allowed to have a "pole" only along the hypersurface cut out by $x = 0$ in $X$, or equivalently rational functions on $X$ that are defined on the open set where $x \neq 0$.

The prime ideals of $R$ correspond to the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ that contain the ideal $(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$.  The prime ideals of $R_f$ correspond to the prime ideals of $R$ that do not contain $f$ (and so do not contain $x$).  Thus, $\text{Spec}(R_f)$ consists of the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ that contain $(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$ but do not contain $x$.  In particular, the closed points (maximal ideals) correspond to the points of $X$ where $x \neq 0$.

Comment: In the last paragraph, is really $R_{(f)}$ the localization at $R\setminus (x^2)$? the ideal $(x^2)$ is not prime...

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I'm sorry... how can I find prime ideals of $R$? In pratice I have to find $Spec(R)$.

Comment: @atricolf: Yes, you're absolutely right.  Will edit.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I'm sorry... but how can I find prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ that contain $(x^3+y^3+z^3)$ but do not contain $x$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for; there isn't any obvious way to list all such ideals. If you take any $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$ and $a \neq 0$, then the maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b,z-c)$ is one such ideal. (These are all the prime ideals you want that are themselves maximal.) Other such prime ideals are ideals such as $I = (x^3+y^3+z^3, -2y^2+xz^4-y^2 z^3)$. Geometrically, the prime ideals you seek correspond to subvarieties of the hypersurface $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$ that are not contained in the plane $x = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce How you find $I=(x^3+y^3...)$?

Comment: I just took an ideal that contained $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ by including it as a generator and then added another generator.  I should have been more careful, because it is possible that the ideal I chose is not prime.  But the point is that there are lots of such prime ideals, because of the geometric correspondence with certain subvarieties.

Comment: So we have that $Spec(R_x)=\{\mbox{maximal ideals}, 12 \mbox{lines} \}$ and this new type of ideals such $I=(x^3+y^3+z^3, ... )$. Is there a method to classify these ideals? The lines are $(y,bx-z)$, $(y,x-bz)$, $(z,y-bx)$, $(z,x-by)$ with $b^3=-1$?

Comment: There is no way to "classify" such ideals by explicitly parametrizing them.  The best way to say it is that the prime ideals are in one-to-one correspondence with the irreducible subvarieties of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$ that are not contained in the plane $x = 0$.  That includes the points $(a,b,c)$ with $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 0$ and $a \neq 0$ (corresponding to maximal idaels) and the lines you described, but also other more complicated subvarieties as well.

Comment: Sorry if I am stressing, but I'd like to know if it is possible to find some of these subvarieties

Comment: Just write down some equations.  For example, $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = -2y^2 + xz^4 - y^2 z^3 = 0$ is one such example.  The only issue is that it may not be irreducible, but then any irreducible component will be an example.  However, you won't be able to systematically write down all examples.  Philosophically, you should be happy with the description in the previous comment, because it is the best that is available and connects the algebra (prime ideals of $R_f$) with the geometry (certain subvarieties of affine space).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10712/discussion-between-arthurstuart-and-michael-joyce)

Answer (score 3):

You can imagine $R$ as the coordinate ring of an affine surface $X$ in $\mathbb A^3$, defined by the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$. In other words, $R=\Gamma(X,O_X)$ is the ring of functions on this surface. In $X$, you have an open subscheme given by $\textrm{Spec }R_f$: it consists of the points on $X$ at which the function $f=x^2$ does not vanish (indeed elements of $R_f$ are of the form $h/x^{2i}$, with $h\in R$ and $i\geq 0$). I leave it to you to interpret the expression "$f(P)\neq 0$" below, geometrically or algebraically - as you prefer. But of course you can view $R_f\subset K(X)=\textrm{Frac }R$ as a certain class of rational functions on $X$. To sum up, we have inclusions (the first open, the second closed): $$\textrm{Spec }R_f=\{P\in \textrm{Spec }R\,|\,f(P)\neq 0\}\subset \textrm{Spec }R\subset \mathbb A^3$$
corresponding to ring homomorphisms (the first arrow is quotient map, the second is the localization at $f$) $$\mathbb C[x,y,z]\to R=\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^3+y^3+z^3)\to R_f.$$ 
Instead, $R_{(f)}=\{r/f^i\,|\,\deg\,r=2i \}=\{g\in R_f\,|\,\deg\,g =0\}\subset R_f$.

I can only think at $\textrm{Spec }R_{(f)}$ in the projective setting: it is an open subscheme of the projective plane curve $\textrm{Proj }R=V_+(x^3+y^3+z^3)\subset \mathbb P_\mathbb C^2=\textrm{Proj }\mathbb C[x,y,z]$. (We can also regard $\textrm{Spec }R$ as the affine cone over $\textrm{Proj }R$. **Added**: In this perspective, the map $\textrm{Spec }R_{f}\to \textrm{Spec }R_{(f)}$, which is the restriction of the quotient map $\mathbb A^3\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb P_\mathbb C^2$, it the morphism corresponding to the inclusion of $\mathbb C$-algebras $R_{(f)}\to R_f$.)

Comment: Ahhh, that must be the correct interpretation of $R_{(f)}$, which I think is Hartshorne's notation.  I've never liked it because it conflicts with $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ if $\mathfrak{p} = (f)$ is prime, and can lead me to spouting nonsense if I encounter it sufficiently early in the morning. :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree the localization notations are infernal!